# calculate the percent change in y variable as a result of reduction in x variable by 10%

Tags: regression

I just want to calculate the percent change in y variable as a result of reduction in x variable by 10%. Is there a code for it in R? for example, if x = particulate matter in air and Y = air pollution level. I just want to see if I reduce particulate matter by 10%, how much percent change will be there in air pollution level?

Comment: Log-log specifications approximate percent change for small changes. Is the 10% threshold important to you?